# Angularjs $resource POST send query string not JSON object (Typescript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-resource

When I write a custom action $resource like this:

```
getEntityResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEntityResource> {


       let addAction: ng.resource.IActionDescriptor = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8085/api/entity/add'
        }
        return <ng.resource.IResourceClass<IEntityResource>>
        this.$resource("http://localhost:8085/api/entity/:entityId", { id: '@id' },  {
          add: addAction,  
        });
```

and call it from the controller like this:

```
this.$mdDialog.hide(this.dataService
            .getEntityResource()
            .add(this.entity,
            () => this.$state.reload()
        ));
```

the call is sending like this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8085/api/entity/add?id=0
```

The webApi action is accepting entity object as parameter not an id:

```
[HttpPost]
public Entity Add(Entity entity)
```

The problem is that it sends the post request with a string parameter (?id=0) and not JSON object.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting any error? Whats the problem?

Comment: It's sending a query string /add?id=0 not a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Your problem is, that you pass the data as second parameter. To pass the data as a JSON object you must do the following:

```
$resource("http://localhost:8085/api/entity/:entityId", 
     {},  
     {params: {id: '@id'}...}
);
```